# Exponential solutions to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

How does it follow that $\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=-\lambda\phi$ where our seperation constant $\lambda>0$ implies an exponential solution with imaginary exponents?  Specifically $e^{\pm\imath\sqrt[]{\lambda}}$.

Then somehow if we want real independent solutions the choices $\cos(x\sqrt[]{\lambda})$ and $\sin(x\sqrt[]{\lambda})$?  My text says $\cos(x\sqrt[]{\lambda})$ and $\sin(x\sqrt[]{\lambda})$ are linear combinations of $e^{\pm\imath\sqrt[]{\lambda}}$ but how?  Does it have something to do with $e^{\imath\pi}=-1$?

Comment: Why did you put "partial differential equations" in the tags ? There is no PDE in your question. (-1) .

Comment: @JJacquelin It is part of a solution to a PDE specifically the heat equation of a 1D rod at equilibrium.  At equilibrium dt=0 and we assume our original equation to only be a function only of x, instead of t and x also we used product solutions to make this particular ODE from our PDE.  In this particular part of the solution yes it is an ODE but I included the tags for context in case there was something important I had not mentioned.  As this problem is a well known and commonly used example for teaching PDE's I didn't think it would be a problem.  Sorry to offend.

Comment: OK. Now I understand. But you should have explain this in your question It is usefull to give some context to a question and that is one of the rules of the forum here. Of course nobody is offended.

Comment: Ya sorry I'm not a math major so I'm never sure when I am over explaining obvious things or under explaining them.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $e^{\pm ix\sqrt {\lambda}}$ not $e^{\pm i\sqrt {\lambda}}$.

This  follows from the fact that $\sin a=\frac {e^{ia}-e^{-ia}} {2i}$ and $\cos a=\frac {e^{ia}+e^{-ia}} 2$.